# I have error while i tried to execute query which return me a path to variable

Tags: python, glob, raw-input

I tried to open multiple files in one location using python

When I tried to execute this small script I get error:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 254, in run_nodebug
>   File "C:\Users\kostrzew\Desktop\REPORTS\MdiAdmin.py", line 21, in 
>   file_path = glob(os.path.join(dir,"*.mdi")) TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

```
import os
import string
import re
import sys
import glob


src = raw_input("Enter source disk location: ")
src = os.path.dirname(src)
for dir,_,_ in os.walk(src):
    file_path = glob(os.path.join(dir,"*.mdi"))
    print(file_path)
```

Comment: What does your title have to do with the question? You're not trying to open any files. You're getting an error when you try to call `glob`.

Comment: Sorry .. i fixed it:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`glob` is the name of the module, the name of the function is `glob.glob`.

```
file_path = glob.glob(os.path.join(dir,"*.mdi"))
```